# Be able to reconstruct or reference React's tree to see parent-child relationships between elements

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I have a need to be able to know how child nodes are associated with their parents and to be able to reference them...

For example:

````
```
<CustomComponent>
  <h1>Hello, World!</h1>

  <CustomComponent>
    <h1>One</h1>
  </CustomComponent>

  <CustomComponent>
    <h1>Two</h1>

    <CustomComponent>
      <h1>Two One</h1>
    </CustomComponent>

    <CustomComponent>
      <h1>Two Two</h1>
    </CustomComponent>
  </CustomComponent>

</CustomComponent>
```
````

As you can see above, there is an inherent tree structure to these components (composite or host) and I'd like to be able to know, at the very minimum, how `CustomComponent`s are nested throughout an entire React application.

I tried a naive solution with the following:

````
```
<CustomComponent id="0">
  <h1>Hello, World!</h1>

  <CustomComponent id="0:1">
    <h1>One</h1>
  </CustomComponent>

  <CustomComponent id="0:2">
    <h1>Two</h1>

    <CustomComponent id="0:2:1">
      <h1>Two One</h1>
    </CustomComponent>

    <CustomComponent id="0:2:2">
      <h1>Two Two</h1>
    </CustomComponent>
  </CustomComponent>

</CustomComponent>
```
````

Obviously this is not an optimal approach as the user would have to define the entire tree structure with `id`s and in addition, if the order in which these components mount into the DOM is not linear so it would be hard to reconstruct the tree and be able to perform logic on their relationship to one another.

Any ideas on how to go about this? Thank you for your time and assistance.

Comment: You mean you need to be able to programmatically "see" the structure? From where? And why? And at what time?

Comment: Yes, you got it! I was thinking that I may need to only see one time, so perhaps at `ReactDom.render(.., .., callback)` but not sure if that would be appropriate. I'm essentially building another scene graph with CustomComponents

Comment: You'll probably have to get the rendered tree structure and walk it manually to figure out what you want. Dunno what the hooks in React, if any, are, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly where I've been stuck at... Needing to see how I can see it, correctly, when needed.

Comment: I don't really understand the use case for this outside of UI testing. Create the structure in your state and then render that state. You can then easily access it from your state as a whole.

Comment: I would try to think if you are asking the right question @Detuned maybe there is a better way, what you're asking looks very un-reacty to me

Comment: You could possibly have the components register themselves in your own custom tree upon rendering. You could use context to provide the node's ancestry so it can provide that in it's registration.

Comment: That was actually my attempt with specifying the `id`s @MichaelLyons, but the unfortunate thing is that I need to be able to reference them after they've been mounted into the DOM so I moved the registering inside of `componentDidMount` which then led me to see that the mounting is not in particular order that would be useful for building a tree.

Comment: Additionally, it would be idea to not have the user need to know the structure by creating these `id`s as that would quite difficult to scale across a large application. Hence why it would be ideal to know of their parent-child relationship without the `id`s.

Comment: I know what you mean, @JanHančič, however, to be able to extend what react has a whole to create a scene graph, I'd need to do something similar here... I really don't want to recreate `react-dom` since I still need all of that functionality but just extended so I can hook into that tree.

Answer (score 1):

While I think it's an abuse of react, you can use `context` to maintain parent-child relationships:

```
let componentId = 0

class CustomComponent extends React.Component {
   constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);

      this.state = {componentId: componentId++};
   }

   getChildContext() {
      return {
         parentId: this.state.componentId
      };
   }

   render() {
      return (
          <div>
              Parent ID: {this.context.parentId}
              {this.props.children}
          </div>
      );
   }
}

CustomComponent.contextTypes = {
    parentId: React.PropTypes.number
}
CustomComponent.childContextTypes = {
    parentId: React.PropTypes.number
};
```

You can then use that to generate `id` or a `className` to search for the component.

You can probably use that to create increasing identifiers in the form `1-2-3...` but that's just an extension of the idea.

You can also use a pure HTML method. In your `componentDidMount` you can find all direct descendants with a specific `class`, e.g. using xPath (`document.evaluate`) but that solution will be a bit slow.

Another possibility is to map the children in `render`, adding the index as property manually. An example (I hope it covers all possibilities).

```js
class CustomComponent extends React.Component {
    mapChildren(children) {
        const thisIndex = this.props.index;
   
        return React.Children.map(children, child => {
            if (child.type === CustomComponent) {
                return React.cloneElement(child, {
                    index: thisIndex + "-" + this.childIndex++
                });            
            } else if (child.props && child.props.children) {
                return React.cloneElement(child, {
                   children: this.mapChildren(child.props.children)
                });            
            } else {
                return child;
            }
        });
    }      

    render() {
        this.childIndex = 1;
        const newChildren = this.mapChildren(this.props.children);
   
        return (
           <div>              
              This ID: {this.props.index}
              {newChildren}
          </div>
        );
    }
}

CustomComponent.propTypes = {
    index: React.PropTypes.string
};
CustomComponent.defaultProps = {
    index: "1"
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <CustomComponent>
     <h1>Title 1</h1>
     <CustomComponent>
         <h1>Title 2</h1>
      </CustomComponent>
      <CustomComponent>
         <h1>Title 3</h1>
         <CustomComponent>
            <h1>Title 4</h1>
         </CustomComponent>         
         <CustomComponent>
            <h1>Title 5</h1>
         </CustomComponent>        
         <div>
            Wrapping div
            <CustomComponent>
               <h1>Title 6</h1>
            </CustomComponent>         
         </div>
      </CustomComponent>
  </CustomComponent>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

However, this could have some performance implications.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That's, in fact, what I have currently. I'm using the `context` to store the components, etc. but as I mentioned earlier (probably not very clearly) that if I create the IDs this way, I won't know the parent-child relationship and I need to construct this tree after the components have been mounted into the DOM, which I've found out that the order in which they mount is not linear as it would be needed for this tree.

I could work around this by generating the tree at the end when everything has been mounted, however, I still have the ID generation issue, etc.

Comment: @Detuned I believe that the constructors are always called in order. The problem is that when the tree changes (e.g. a component is inserted) the order will be broken.

Comment: An option would also be to run a `map` over `children` and detect `CustomComponent` to pass them an index as a property. However, that would be a problem if `CustomComponent` is not a direct child.

Comment: @Detuned I have added an example of child mapping. That could actually be your solution.

Comment: This is great! The only thing I'd be concerned with here is whether the construction of the relationships here will be held when components are added/removed. In addition, how would this work in cases where the `render` method includes other composite components that have other surfaces. I don't believe this will traverse the entire tree, is that correct? Given that you'd have to render the other component (e.g. `CustomHeader` that has its own `CustomComponent` that parent-child relationship between the main parent and the sub parent-children may be broken?

Comment: @Detuned I think the relationships will hold even with updates, however the entire tree can be updated in that case. I am not entirely sure about nested components, I tested it with only with a wrapping `<div>`. This will really traverse the entire tree, therefore the number of components can be significant and there can be a performance impact. I would recommend using pure rendering because that should stop the traversing as soon as possible.

Comment: Yeah, I'm on the same page as you. I just tested it with another nested component, since this structure will need to be maintained throughout an entire app and the nested components are reset as we break out of the logic here... Such a tricky problem.... :(

Comment: You are right, I haven't realized that it would work but it will break the states in all nested components because of the cloning...

Comment: Thanks for the effort, again... I think we were on the same track and hit the same wall. I have made an issue on the React github page to see if we can get more feedback when needing to see React's tree or whether there is a better way of doing this.

Comment: @Detuned Unfortunately I don't know your exact use case but if you don't need the info during render, note that you can use the same approach (iterating over `props.children`) even outside the `render` method but without cloning the components. Technically, you should be able to go over the whole component tree from your top component.

Comment: It's a unique situation where I'm building an augmented scene graph to do animations... but I think this approach wouldn't work as referenced composite components (i.e. components not directly in the render) would break the iteration mapping. At least from what I tried...

I may have to resort to building a custom renderer... :(